# Load popup.html from chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a page action popup that works when loaded from the manifest file.  However I want to get the tab information for the tab that was clicked to launch the popup.  I can get the tab information from chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener but I don't know how to launch popup.html from inside pageAction.onClicked.

Answer (score 2):

You [cannot](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked) have both a `pageAction.onClicked`:

> `onClicked`
>
> This event will not fire if the page action has a popup.

What you can do, though, is fetching the current tab information with the [Tabs module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent) when the popup is loaded:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    // tab contains information about the current tab
});
```

Comment: I have the following code that gets called from a button on the popup.  The tab is undefined in the ReLog function.

function OnLogin( )
{
  chrome.tabs.getCurrent( function( tab ){ ReLog( tab );} );
}

function ReLog( tab )
{
  console.log( "Login Requested" );
  returnURL=tab.url;
...
}

Comment: @Rob: Are you sure? Do you get the "Login Requested" log but does `tab.url` fail?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting BTW.  Yeah, I set a breakpoint to single step through ReLog.  I think it is treating the popup as a tabless DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for what I wanted to do.  On the background page:

```
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(OnActiveChanged);  
function OnActiveChanged( tabId, selectInfo )  
{  
  chrome.tabs.get( tabId, function( tab ){  
    window.activeTab = tab;  
  } );  
}
```

This captures the tab each time the tab changes.  Then in my popup's function gets the tab from the background page:

```
function OnLogin( )  
{
  backgroundWindow = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();  
  var activeTab = backgroundWindow.activeTab;  
...  
}
```

Be careful when you debug the code though.  The debugger causes a tab change event which changes the tab away from the tab that launched the popup.